# calculate 95 percentile on multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.6, percentile

I want to calculate 95 percentile on multiple lists like this :

```
import numpy as np
list_a = [0, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5]
list_b = [0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 4]

list_t = []
list_t.extend(list_a)
list_t.extend(list_b)
list_t_pc = np.percentile(list_t, 95)
print('percentile of list total percentile : '+str(list_t_pc))
```

Output :

```
percentile of list total : 7.799999999999997
```

But in my case I collect data day by day and i can't save all values in list. I can save one value by day (like a mean, max or a percentil). So to get the nearest value of the 95 percentile I do :

```
import numpy as np
day_1 = [0, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5]
day_2 = [0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 4]

day_1_pc = np.percentile(day_1, 95)
day_2_pc = np.percentile(day_2, 95)

list_pc = [day_1_pc, day_2_pc]
print('percentile of percentile : '+str(np.percentile(list_pc, 95)))
```

Output :

```
percentile of percentile : 8.6
```

Is there a way to calculate a closer value ?

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, just join the lists before calculating a percentile. ```np.percentile(list_a + list_b,95)```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please rephrase it to make it easier to parse, and formulate a more exact question of what, precisely, you want to calculate.

Comment: I edited my post maybe is more clearer

Comment: Why can't you save the previous results? Can't you store it in a file or something like so? And how do you save only a single value from previous days?

Comment: Previous result are saved in a database but i'm limited by the size of entries. So I save just few values to not reach storage limit.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to calculate the percentile.
Perhaps it helps if you consider the way the percentiles are calculated in numpy.
Here is the description of the method
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_linear_interpolation_between_closest_ranks_method

I wrote a simple program to mimic the algorithm used.

```python
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import math

def percentile(inList,value):
    sList=sorted(inList)
    x=len(sList)
    rank=(value/100.0*(x-1))+1
    frac,whole=math.modf(rank)
    a=sList[int(whole)-1]
    b=sList[int(whole)]
    c=frac*(b-a)
    p=a+c
    return p


list_a = [0, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5]
list_b = [0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 4]

print percentile(list_a,95)
print percentile(list_b,95)
print percentile(list_a+list_b,95)
listc=[8.75,5.75]
print percentile(listc,95)
```

Comment: How does this help the user? He is already using numpy's percentile function and his problem does not lie there.

Comment: numpys percentile function is a black box. If he understands, whats going on inside, he is more likely to find a way to get what he wants. Maybe he can try a different variant to calculate the percentile, or tweak the algorithm. But I am afraid that the idea he has does not work at all.

Comment: I wasn't aware it was such a black box. 
But we both agree that what the user is doing does not work at all.